# No running my pm2 in server

Tags: node.js, server, pm2

I have server with node and PM2 and when I do pm2 list or pm2 logs, it appeared Starting PM2 daemon...

And nothing more. I have 2 services started but I can't see it.

Comment: Make sure you are starting your services with same user as you're running pm2 list with. I mean if you start your services with root and then run pm2 list as another user you will not see anything.

Answer (score 0):

About pm2,it is explained in detail [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

Answer (score 0):

It is related to the `PM2_HOME` env variable.
By default, it is relative to current user (~/.pm2).

You have to make sure this environnement variable is the same for all the users if you want them to access the same PM2 instance.

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/specifics/#multiple-pm2-on-the-same-server